# How to change a Website Popup words to normal?

Tags: javascript, java

The following is from Google Chrome

[Image of the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liyYy.jpg)

The highlighted words are popups, How can I turn them into normal text?

Comment: Welcome to SO Dragon. Please edit your question to include what the exact problem is and what you expect.  As it sits now your question is very vague.

Comment: Hello sir, Its about data-tooltip at Chrome Elements. there is image in the post. im only at 1 reputation they says " you can't embed image until ur 10 reputation "

https://i.stack.imgur.com/liyYy.jpg

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. What do you mean by "normal words"?

Comment: The popup after you click on text, they're the english ones, to be exact i wanna change those chinese highlighted words into the english popup'ed ones!! check image please, i've opened Google Chrome Console so you can see HTML words just in case

data-tooltip ( before ) to original

Comment: Umm ... you would need to modify the software (app, webserver, whatever) that is generating the page.  Or maybe implement some kind of trusted browser plugin.  Is that what you are talking about?  (Which?)